# Can I know who send a certain message in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I've noticed that some apps send incorrect messages to a certain queue in RabbitMQ. Since lots of apps can access RabbitMQ in my environment, it's too difficult to identify the producers by reviewing codes.

Is there any way to find the producers? Do I need some monitoring tools?

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/09/09/rabbitmq-tracing-a-ui-for-the-firehose/ how about this?

Comment: firehose can log all the messages, but it seems that I can't get the producer from the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without modifying the clients.

The [AMQP](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html) protocol provides the `app-id` property exactly for that purpose. Message publishers should set the `app-id` when publishing messages to RabbitMQ so that consumers can infer the source of the message.